# Spiking Neural Network Classifier Implementation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, biological-neural-network

Are there any machine learning packages that implement spiking neural networks? or any other stand-alone implementations of them that could get me started to work with?

Answer (score 4):

A python library named Brian ought to be useful for you.

There's also what I believe is a programing language named NEURON, but Brian is fairly easy to learn, at least for the basics. It took me a while though to figure out how to do a couple small things, since its a really high level language or whatnot.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is Brian a machine learning package to classify data, or just a simple demo?

Comment: Well, it should be able to classify. Thats what I'm trying to get it to do actually. Nope, its not just a simple demo, its the real deal, I think. It can simulate neurons according to, I think, any differential equation. You can modify weights and delays between neurons and all. Plus, it uses scipy library and C libraries for computationally intensive portions to make the runtime just a bit slower than what would be done in a C implementation.

Comment: Anyhow, if you ever get stuck on something while using Brian, message me on SO here and I can help. It can get confusing to use such a high level set of constructs to do really specific things like explicitly setting the delay line matrix or weight matrix.

Comment: could you please tell me the application of Brian? what is it used for? what is the input, what is the output? Have you seen any examples of Brian being used for classification? thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, Brian is a general purpose spiking neural network simulator. It can be used for computational neuroscience, but seeing as it uses neurons which can learn, it can also be used for classification.

Inputs can be made by having objects which represent input neurons that will emit spikes at certain times. As such, one can encode anything in a list of spikes times.

Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier.

Answer (score 1):

There are several other SNN platforms these days that allows you to run classification. I have worked with NeuCube (https://kedri.aut.ac.nz/R-and-D-Systems/neucube) which is a Matlab & Java-based SNN platform.

Also, check out Akida Development Environment (ADE) from Brainchip Inc (https://brainchipinc.com/). One of the best features of ADE is that it's APIs are based on tensorflow/keras structure and also supports CNN2SNN converter to use your deep learning models in SNN domain. SNN models developed using this platform can be deployed on their neuromorphic processor Akida.

I believe there are other platforms such as PyNN and Nengo (compatibility to run models on Loihi) within the SNN domain.

Answer (score 0):

Here are links for brain simulator

[https://github.com/brian-team/brian2](http://briansimulator.org/)

[https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2605403/](http://briansimulator.org/)

http://briansimulator.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Nengo Loihi library for deployment not only of spiking neural networks but also neuromorphic neural networks.
here's the link to their website: https://www.nengo.ai/nengo-loihi/v1.0.0/index.html

You can find on Kaggle an implementation of the ciphar10 dataset, locally loaded, using Nengo Loihi library. Here's the link:
https://www.kaggle.com/migueltoms/neuromorphic-ciphar-10-loihi-comparison-of-results